# Change image extension on submission

Tags: webforms, users

I am using D7.12 with webform 3.18. I want to change the image extension from png to jpg of the image uploaded through the form before saving it to database. I tried mytheme_webform_submission_presave() in template.php but didn't help me. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [imagecache actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module to auto convert images from one extension to other.

Module Project page tells it provides

> File Format switcher - If you need tranparency in JPGs : make them
>   PNG. If your PNG thumbnails are 30K each, save them as JPGs. (This is
>   distributed as part of the color-actions submodule)

Comment: Thanks Anil. But how can integrate this with images uploaded through webform? There is no option to select image style in webform admin side. Is there any hook that i can pass image file and return the changed extension image?

Comment: I tried using this module with the theme_image_style() and it is working fine except switching file format :(